# Writing a basic PostScript script by hand

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, postscript, gimp

I wanted to try and manually code a PostScript file. Why? Why not. From Wikipedia, I copied and pasted their basic `Hello World` program for `PostScript` which is:

```
%!PS
/Courier             % name the desired font
20 selectfont        % choose the size in points and establish 
                     % the font as the current one
72 500 moveto        % position the current point at 
                     % coordinates 72, 500 (the origin is at the 
                     % lower-left corner of the page)
(Hello world!) show  % stroke the text in parentheses
showpage             % print all on the page
```

When I try to open it in `GIMP`, I get

> Opening 'Hello World.ps' failed. Could not interpret file 'Hello World.ps'

I can use `ImageMagick` to convert the file

```
convert "Hello World.ps" "Hello World.pdf"
convert "Hello World.ps" "Hello World.eps"
```

The PDF opens successfully and displays 'Hello World' in Courier.
The EPS yields the same error as the PS.

- Is there something wrong with the syntax of the PS file?
- Are PS files just not meant to be viewed directly, and should instead be viewed in a containing format like PDF?
- Is GIMP just not able to handle this particular format of PS file?

Comment: There are a lot of good old books for rolling your own PS. E.g., http://www-cdf.fnal.gov/offline/PostScript/BLUEBOOK.PDF  You might want to also see http://ssc.sagepub.com/content/22/4/512 for a technical drawing focus.  Here's a working paper version of the article: https://subversion.american.edu/aisaac/wp/psdraw20030415.pdf  If you get really serious, try Casselman's book: http://www.math.ubc.ca/~cass/graphics/manual/

Comment: the economists article is just what I'm looking for, thanks! The other links look good too

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your questions, one by one:

1. You PostScript file is completely OK.
2. PostScript files can be viewed directly if you use a PostScript-capable viewer. *(BTW: PDF may be regarded as a 'container format' -- but it never embeds a PostScript file for 'viewing'...)*
3. For Gimp to be able and handle PS/EPS files, you need a working **[Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.15/Readme.htm)** (**[installation link](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/)**) on your system.

The same as point '3.' is true for your `convert` command: ImageMagick cannot handle PS/EPS or PDF input files unless there is a functional Ghostscript installation available on the local system. This would work as a so-called *'delegate'*, employed by ImageMagick to handle file formats which it cannot handle itself. A delegate converts such a format into a raster file, which ImageMagick in turn can then take over for further processing.

To check for available ImageMagick delegates, run these commands:

```
convert -list delegate

convert -list delegate | grep -Ei --color '(eps|ps|pdf)'
```

Comment: Cool, number 3 really answers it all. I'm actually running gimp on a windows machine and ImageMagick in a linux VPS, so the linux box has ghost script and plenty of other delegates for ImageMagick, but the windows box does not.